# Insert contents of a text file recursively into mysql database Erlang

Tags: file, list, recursion, erlang

I'm having problem inserting a .txt file contents into my MySQL DB recursively.

Right now i have a function that reads a .txt file and gets a specific line from the file. It succeeds on inserting a specific line to an List where i then insert it into the MySQL DB but when i try to go from line 1 to n and do each line sepperatly I am truly lost.

I've tried to use the erlang:length() to gather the max lenght of the list and make it reduce by one for each line i insert but it wont work. I've tried something like this.

```
start() ->
    Lines = into_list("Filepath"),
    LineNR = erlang:length(Lines),
    getLine(LineNR, Lines).

getLine(NewLineNR, List) when NewLineNR >= 0 ->
    NewNewLineNR = NewLineNR - 1,
    task(NewNewLineNR, List).

task(NewLineNR, List) ->      
    Line = line_nr( NewLineNR , List),
    [List] = string:tokens(Line, ","),
    Insert = [List],
    %%The insertion in the DB happens here
    insert_to_db(Insert),
    getLine(NewLineNR, List).
```

But it crashed and i dont know why. Tips are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What crash report did you get?

Comment: None, it just stops working. Using Eclipse if that is any help.

Comment: I fault searched this and i made some error handling, seems like my list becomes empty somewhere in these lines?

Comment: What does `line_nr` do / return?  
What's the data structure that `into_list` returns?  Is it just a list of strings?

Comment: line_nr gets a specific line (Which is the value of "NewLineNR") and into_list returns a list of strings like this:     1 4 15 43
2 4 12 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens when NewLineNR = -1?  Erlang will freak out because it can't match any of the getLine clauses.

You can do this a little simpler though (assuming `line_nr` just gets line x out of the list).  In Erlang you can use pattern matching to control the program flow, instead of relying on keeping track of which item in the list you are working with:

```
start() ->
    Lines = into_list("Filepath"),
    task(Lines).

task([Head | Tail]) ->      
    TokensList = string:tokens(Head, ","),
    %%The insertion in the DB happens here
    insert_to_db(TokensList),
    task(Tail);

task([]) -> done.
```

This version uses list head/tail pattern matching to help recurse through the list.  Assuming `into_list` just reads the file into a list of strings, the code does the following:

1. Read file into list
2. Tokenize first entry in list
3. Insert into DB
4. Repeat 2-3 on remainder of list until list is empty.
5. Return `done` atom when list is empty.

Comment: Not sure it's even getting to -1. If he's using lists:nth, it would freak out right when he got to 0.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells True.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to understand it a little bit more. Thing is now that i get "** exception error: no match of right hand side value" when I am trying to sepperate the "," from each tokenlist.

Comment: @BorisMeister Can you add the line `io:fwrite("~w~n", [Head]),` before the `string:tokens` line and reply back with the output?  I'd like to see what you're passing into string:tokens.

Comment: Commented the insert_to_db() and added your line, it gave me loads of lines like this:


[50,48,49,50,49,50,49,55,44,53,49,56,46,56,51,48,48,44,53,50,48,46,48,48,48,48,44,53,48,49,46,50,51,48,48,44,53,48,56,46,57,51,48,48,44,50,55,48,53,55,52,48,48,10]

Comment: That line passes through string:tokens just fine for me. @BorisMeister - Are you trying to remove the comma *after* the call to string:tokens? Because string:tokens removes it for you.

Comment: It does yea, but I know the problem now. I insert the correct values but my insertion looks like this: [A,B,C,D,E,F] and the token that I'm inserting now is like: [[A,B,C,D,E,F]] so thats why there where no right hand side value! Is there possible to split the tokens in a good way?

Comment: For clearing purposes i ment that i want the Tokenslist which looks like this: [[A,B,C,D,E,F]] to become this: [[A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F]]

Comment: Discard my latest comments. It works as intended, Just had to tweak the TokensList to fit my insertion function. Thanks @AlexMoore !